# Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm. PS256

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

I use provided code in this [document](https://cloud.yandex.com/en-ru/docs/iam/operations/iam-token/create-for-sa#via-jwt). The difference here is only values of some account variables. Algorithm used for generate private key (that stored in private.pem file) is RSA_2048.

The main goal is achive JWT with PS256 encryption algorithm.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Jose;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceAccountId = "myServiceAccountId";
        var keyId = "myKeyId
        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

        var headers = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "kid", keyId }
        };

        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "aud", "someAudience" },
            { "iss", serviceAccountId },
            { "iat", now },
            { "exp", now + 3600 }
        };

        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKeyParams;
        using (var pemStream = File.OpenText("private.pem"))
        {
            privateKeyParams = new PemReader(pemStream).ReadObject() as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
        }

        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKeyParams));
            string encodedToken = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.PS256, headers);
        }
    }
}
```

On line:

```
string encodedToken = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.PS256, headers);
```

I receive an exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.)
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash(Byte[] hash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.SignData(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 count, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.SignData(Byte[] data, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at Jose.RsaPssUsingSha.Sign(Byte[] securedInput, Object key)
   at Jose.JWT.EncodeBytes(Byte[] payload, Object key, JwsAlgorithm algorithm, IDictionary`2 extraHeaders, JwtSettings settings)
   at Jose.JWT.Encode(String payload, Object key, JwsAlgorithm algorithm, IDictionary`2 extraHeaders, JwtSettings settings)
   at Jose.JWT.Encode(Object payload, Object key, JwsAlgorithm algorithm, IDictionary`2 extraHeaders, JwtSettings settings)
```

I use jwt-jose package for encoding.

Comment: Which .NET version are you running? Have a look at this: https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#rs--and-ps--family

Comment: there's a typo in the line `var keyId = "myKeyId`

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on .Net Framework on Windows just replace RSACryptoServiceProvider with RSACng

`using (var rsa = new RSACng())`

If you're on .Net Core it becomes a bit more complicated as it relies on OS crypto libraries. You should detect platform in your code and use either RSACng for Windows or RSAOpenSsl on Linux (available on .Net 6)

`using (RSA rsa = new RSAOpenSsl())`

Answer (score 0):

I confront the same error, what I do is like follow

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Value.Cer);
using var csp =  (RSA) cert.PublicKey.Key;
var bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(content, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```

All went fine in .Net 6 but throws error when using framework 4.8.

The previous answer almost takes me there.

I find an workaround as below:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(content.CertificateContentRaw));
var csp = new RSACng();
var xml = cert.GetRSAPublicKey().ToXmlString(false);
csp.FromXmlString(xml);
```